# How to callback funtion in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with the callback function in Reactjs

I have function show data

```
const handleShowData = (nodeData, data) => {
     setInputName(nodeData.name);
     setInputAddress(nodeData.address)
     handleUpdateData(data);
}
```

After that, I wanna call this function onClose button.

```
<InfoDialog
  open={isOpenDialog}
  labelButtonOk="OK"
  onClose={() => {
   handleShowData();
   }
  }
title={titleDialog}
/>
```

So, how do we define nodeData and data for **handleShowData();** in close event?

Comment: You type them between the `(` and `)` after the function name. This is fundamental JS.

Comment: I'm rusty in react, but didn't you forget to add the arrow (=>) to the function definition in handleShowData?

Comment: @Bahax You are correct. He's not assigning it as a function unless he uses `(nodeData, data) => {...`. I'm wondering if the code he provided even runs.

Comment: Sorry, the type is missing. Yeah, but when it runs the error notifies that nodeData and data is not defined?

Comment: I think onClose={handleShowData} , and any params will be passed from event to the function

Comment: @ChemiAdel — That's great if they want to pass the event to `nodeData` and `undefined` to `data`… but I doubt they do.